# i want radio button functionality in checkbox and that checkbox is also toggle..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

This Is CheckBox Code

```
<input type="checkbox" class="ascsection radio" id="checkbox-choice-t-6a" value="" />
<label for="checkbox-choice-t-6a" style="border: 1px solid #2d5f7c;width:90px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px;border-top-left-radius:4px;font-family:SertoJerusalem;">Abc</label>

<input type="checkbox" class="ascsyriac radio" id="checkbox-choice-t-6b" value="" />
<label for="checkbox-choice-t-6b" style="border: 1px solid #2d5f7c;width:90px;border-bottom-right-radius:4px;border-top-right-radius:4px;font-family:SertoJerusalem;">ܐ ܒ</label>
```

i want radio button functionality in this two checkbox and also toggle.

means i load page first time my two checkbox unchecked.
then i one checkboc abc checked.now i am second checkbox def checked that time abc unchecked.and now click on again def then def checkbox unchecked.

Thanks In Advance...

Generate this Type Class

```
    <div class="ui-checkbox">
<input id="checkbox-choice-t-6a" class="ascsection radio" name="checkbox-choice-t-61" value="" type="checkbox">
<label class="ui-checkbox-off ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-first-child" for="checkbox-choice-t-6a" style="border: 1px solid #2d5f7c;width:90px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px;border-top-left-radius:4px;font-family:SertoJerusalem;" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="checkbox-off" data-theme="c" data-mini="false">
<span class="ui-btn-inner">
<span class="ui-btn-text">Abc</span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow"> </span>
</span>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: *"Please Do"* - Um...where did you get stuck when you tried? Maybe start with a `change` or `click` event handler bound to both checkboxes, then... Regarding your markup, wouldn't it make more sense if both checkboxes had the same class as a way to group them?

Comment: So, why radios are made to? Although you can customize it simply use js interactivity to achieve this.

Comment: this my checkbox toggle but any time one checkbox checked then click on another that time first checkbox unchecked so please help

Comment: i want checkbox but toggle and if any one is checked and then click on another remove checked in first and also click on checked chckbox than remove checked on that checkbox understand..?

Comment: why do you want a checkbox with radio functionality, and not just use a radio instead

Comment: @A.Lau but i want two functionality 1-toggle checkbox and 2-radio button functionality so. please help me and read my question proper

Comment: i tried. if one checkbox checked then click another that time remove ui-checkbox-off, ui-icon-checkbox-on, ui-btn-active but not working so help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code.

I have added radio class for both checkbox for select all the checkbox which need radio button functionality.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".radio").click(function() {
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    if (isChecked) {
      $(".radio").prop("checked", false);
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="abc radio" id="chkbox1" value="" />
<label for="chkbox1" style="border: 1px solid #2d5f7c;width:90px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px;border-top-left-radius:4px;font-family:SertoJerusalem;">Abc</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="def radio" id="chkbox2" value="" />
<label for="chkbox2" style="border: 1px solid #2d5f7c;width:90px;border-bottom-right-radius:4px;border-top-right-radius:4px;font-family:SertoJerusalem;">Def</label>
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: `$(this).prop("checked")` is a complicated way of saying `this.checked`. You don't need `$(this).prop("checked", true)` inside the if if you only uncheck the *other* ones...

Comment: @nnnnnn $(this).prop("checked") and this.checked both are give same value.
First I unchecked all the checkbox, so it unchecked current checkbox also.
Then only I manually checked current check box.

Comment: *"$(this).prop("checked") and this.checked both are give same value."* - I know. That's what I already said. But `this.checked` is shorter, more efficient, and easier to read.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes. now I update my code. Thanks for your information.

Comment: @balachandar this code is not working in my project because my checkbox is generate auto ui-checkbox class in my project

Comment: Please provide html how the check is generated in your project.

Comment: @balachandar i had added auto generated class in my question

Comment: @K-Series It working fine for me. Please provide two check box html string.

Comment: @balachandar i change checkbox html there is my project html code so you watch

Comment: @K-Series check this fiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/L16nx166/1/
it's working. If you still not working. please change the fiddle link. and provide to me.

Comment: @K-Series ...answers are meant to give you a hint, change `$(".radio")` to the selector you need `$(".abc, .def")` or whatever. Should not be *that* hard ;)

Comment: Thanks @balachandar i got solution

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $ckb = $(".ckb"); // yes, add a .ckb to your checkboxes.

$ckb.on("change", function() {
  $ckb.not(this).prop("checked", !this.checked && $ckb.filter(":checked").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1" value="a" class="ckb abc" />
<label for="chkbox1">A</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox2" value="b" class="ckb def" />
<label for="chkbox2">B</label>
```